# How to avoid data repetition in RecyclerView - Android?

Tags: android, mongodb, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a wallpaper app using `mongodb`. I'm retrieving data from database and displaying it on my `recyclerView` by the help of a `data-model` class without any problem. Also I'm using swipe refresh layout to allow user for refreshing the `recyclerView` for new data.

But now the problem is how can I avoid data repetition and show only new posts to the user. I meant if there are 5 pics are there in my db in my first query I'll get those 5 so when the user will refresh the layout again the `recyclerView`'s item is increased to 10 and I wanna avoid this I want to show them new pics only when the posts in db will be increased to 6 or more.

I think this data avoid concept is also used in social media apps. but for this context I wonder what I have to do?

Data model class:

```
public class TimelineData {
    private String type, time, img_link;

    public TimelineData(String type, String time, String img_link) {
        this.type = type;//type means what type of wallpaper
        this.time = time;
        this.img_link = img_link;
    }


    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getImg_link() {
        return img_link;
    }

}
```

Adding Data to recyclerview:

```
private List<TimelineData> timelineDataList = new ArrayList<>();

public void onCreateView() {
    recyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    recyclerview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerview.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));
    //Setting Adapter
    adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Fetching data from server
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.connect();

    //Getting Data from server
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("timeline_posts","all");
        socket.emit("data",obj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
void addTimelineData(String type,String time,String img_link) {
    timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(type,time,img_link));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)args[0];
                          for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                   try {
                       JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                       post_type=ob.getString("post_type");


                       post_time=ob.getString("time");

                       post_link=ob.getString("img_link");

                       addTimelineData(post_type,post_time,post_link);

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: can you show us the code where you add data to the recycler view (the adapter)?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque please check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try cleaning the data source whenever you get new data, that way you'll always reinsert the complete dataset, if you have new data it will be inserted with the old one and you don't have to worry about repeated data in the mobile app, only in the server.

```
 private List<TimelineData> timelineDataList=new ArrayList<>() ;
 public void onCreateView(){
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));
    //Setting Adapter
    adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Fetching data from server
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.connect();

    //Getting Data from server
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("timeline_posts","all");
        socket.emit("data",obj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
void addTimelineData(String type,String time,String img_link){
     boolean isRepeated = false;
     for(TimelineData data : timelineDataList){
         if(data.getTime().equals(time)){
           isRepeated = true;
         }
     }
     if(!isRepeated){
        timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(type,time,img_link));
     }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener(){

@Override
public void call(final Object... args){
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)args[0];
         timelineDataList.clear(); //clear data before inserting new one
                      for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
               try {
                   JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   post_type=ob.getString("post_type");


                   post_time=ob.getString("time");

                   post_link=ob.getString("img_link");

                   addTimelineData(post_type,post_time,post_link);

               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }
}
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and great answer. But don't you think it would be inefficient if I'm caching the data of recyclerview

Comment: it would indeed, but I'm offering the quickest answer. If you want a more elaborate one, answer me this. Is there any way to uniquely identify your time line data? Any of these is unique type,time,img_link? (I'm guessing time is, but you need to tell me)

Comment: I've edited the post with a new alternative, if **time** is unique to each timelinedata you can use it as some sort of **id** and simply add the new timelinedata only if the time does not match with a time in the timelineDataList

Comment: if time isn't unique you could do the same verification with any other attribute that you think can uniquely identifiy a timelinedata :)

Comment: sir again thanks for your great answer but it's not showing data for the first time even

Comment: I tried to use a **refresh_counter** and increased it in *emitter_listener* then checked if counter>1 then your given rule otherwise normal add to list . At first time it's showing data but in next refresh your given code is giving **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**

Comment: Then I tried to perform normal for loop but now recyclerview is showing unique repetition that means posts are repeating as a power of two means second post is repeted twice then third is 4 then 8 likewise they are increasing . I'm flabbergasted by this behavior

Comment: sorry, i forgot you can't edit an array list whilst iterating through it, I've edited the answer :)

Comment: Great answer I was stuck in a similar  problem but this solution helped me . Thanks a lot you're an ingenious indeed @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque sir one more help sometimes it's skipping posts I don't know why and how could you help me to fix this

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque sir could you please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49737090/8027365)

Answer (score 1):

before you add new elements to the wallpaper list, check to see if an object with that id exist in the list. if it does, skip it, else add it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and answer sir . But how can I check that means those data are there in a data model class and not an arraylist

Comment: oh sorry I missed that. Then that will mean you will need to reimplement your recycler view without data models

Comment: so you're saying that I should use arraylist directly instead of data models?

Comment: you can just add another field (id) to the TimelineData  (because maybe you can get two wallpapers with the same time). If you are getting more wallpapers just check the id of each item and see if you have it locally if not just add it to your list otherwise just ignore it