# Why recyclerview adapter is not setting data properly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Few days ago, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49638838/8027365)  for avoiding repetition of `reycylerview` items whose accepted answer helped me to avoid data repetition.

But now I am facing new problems like: not showing all items sometimes only one like this . The real problem is even after getting all items from server properly data is not shown in `recyclerView` properly .Data are skipped randomly. I don't understand where the problem is. I even tried to use `for loop` instead of `foreach` but result was not different. Can anyone please help to fix this? It has been pain in the neck from last one week.

Code:

```
private List<TimelineData> timelineDataList=new ArrayList<>() ;
 public void onCreateView(){
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));
    //Setting Adapter
    adapter=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Fetching data from server
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.connect();

    //Getting Data from server
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("timeline_posts","all");
        socket.emit("data",obj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
void addTimelineData(String type,String time,String img_link){
     boolean isRepeated = false;
     for(TimelineData data : timelineDataList){
         if(data.getTime().equals(time)){
           isRepeated = true;
         }
     }
     if(!isRepeated){
        timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(type,time,img_link));
     }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener(){

@Override
public void call(final Object... args){
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)args[0];
         timelineDataList.clear(); //clear data before inserting new one
                      for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
               try {
                   JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   post_type=ob.getString("post_type");


                   post_time=ob.getString("time");

                   post_link=ob.getString("img_link");

                   addTimelineData(post_type,post_time,post_link);

               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }
}
};
```

**Adapter Code**:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( CustomRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {


    //Fetching TimelineData
    TimelineData timelineData=totalList.get(position);



    ///Here I'm getting and converting array of image links which are there in jsonObject to arraylist
    //Getting Imglink
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = gson.fromJson(timelineData.getImg_link(), type);
    //Setting ViewPager
    CustomPagerAdapter adp=new CustomPagerAdapter(arrayList);
    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    holder.pager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
    holder.pager.clearAnimation();
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    holder.pager.setAdapter(adp);
    holder.pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
   }
```

Comment: You have problem in CustomPagerAdapter or CustomRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: @Khemraj could you please point out the problem

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `notifyDataSetChnaged()` very quickly, change notify method by this. So that you notify only selected item which you inserted.

**Recommended method :** You will put below code in your adapter and call this method from `for loop` where you were setting `notifyDataSetChnaged` here `String s` will be replaced by your model class. By this way you just notify only one element when inserting one element. This will also create some inserting animation automatically.

```
public void insertItemInList(String s) {
    if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(s);
    notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
}
```

Or

You can call notify outside for loop when your work is done like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        post_type=ob.getString("post_type");
        post_time=ob.getString("time");
        post_link=ob.getString("img_link");
        addTimelineData(post_type,post_time,post_link);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Issue is that you are notifying adapter rapidly, it can also lead to UI inconsistency.

Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: great answer sir it solved my issue . By the way I couldn't understand the first part of your answer could you please elaborate that

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the data list in the non-UI thread which could cause problems in the RecyclerView. Instead, you should collect all the data in tempTimelineDataList at once and update the adapted timelineDataList in the UI thread.